# Join tables with dates within intervals of 5 min (get avg)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, timestamp, average

I want to join two tables based on timestamp, the problem is that both tables didn't had the exact same timestamp so i want to join them using a near timestamp using a 5 minute interval.

This query needs to be done using  2 `Common table expressions`, each common table expression needs to get the `timestamps` and `group them` by `AVG` so they can match

```
Freezer |       Timestamp      | Temperature_1
 1      2018-04-25 09:45:00       10  
 1      2018-04-25 09:50:00       11   
 1      2018-04-25 09:55:00       11


Freezer |       Timestamp      | Temperature_2
 1      2018-04-25 09:46:00       15  
 1      2018-04-25 09:52:00       13   
 1      2018-04-25 09:59:00       12
```

My desired result would be:

```
Freezer |       Timestamp      | Temperature_1 | Temperature_2
 1      2018-04-25 09:45:00       10             15
 1      2018-04-25 09:50:00       11             13
 1      2018-04-25 09:55:00       11             12
```

The current query that i'm working on is:

```
WITH Temperatures_1 (
SELECT Freezer, Temperature_1, Timestamp
FROM TABLE_A
),

WITH Temperatures_2 (
SELECT Freezer, Temperature_2, Timestamp
FROM TABLE_B
)

SELECT A.Freezer, A.Timestamp, Temperature_1, Temperature_2
FROM Temperatures_1 as A
RIGHT JOIN Temperatures_2 as B
ON A.FREEZER = B.FREEZER
WHERE A.Timestamp = B.Timestamp
```

Comment: Please please please be careful with the words you choose when asking a programming question.  You asked to use the "nearest timestamp using a 5 minute interval."   Then you say you want "9:59" to join to "9:55", when actually the NEAREST 5-minute interval to "9:59" is "10:00".   Please re-word your question to state exactly what you are trying to achieve.   I don't even want to think about what you might mean with "group them by AVG so they can match".   That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two tables based on timestamps with a 5 minute interval from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032040/join-two-tables-based-on-timestamps-with-a-5-minute-interval-from-each-other)

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question that you marked as answered?

Comment: Yes, this is a different problem, during the last question i only wanted to get the interval, now i am doing 2 different CTEs and i want to use the AVG function

Comment: Where is your attempt to use AVG, and what error did you get?   What are you trying to AVG?

Comment: Why do you want to use CTE, Group by & AVG when you can get expected outcome easily?

Answer (score 1):

You should may want to modify your join criteria instead of filtering the output.  Use `BETWEEN` to bracket your join value on the timestamps.  I chose +/- 150 seconds because that's half of 2-1/2 minutes to either side (5-minute range to match).  You may need something different.

```
;WITH Temperatures_1 (
SELECT Freezer, Temperature_1, Timestamp
FROM TABLE_A
),

WITH Temperatures_2 (
SELECT Freezer, Temperature_2, Timestamp
FROM TABLE_B
)

SELECT A.Freezer, A.Timestamp, Temperature_1, Temperature_2
FROM Temperatures_1 as A
RIGHT JOIN Temperatures_2 as B
ON A.FREEZER = B.FREEZER 
    AND A.Timestamp BETWEEN (DATEADD(SECOND, -150, B.Timestamp) 
                            AND (DATEADD(SECOND, 150, B.Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the key of join two table by adding the timestamp. The timestamp you should need to approximate the datetime on both side tables A and B tables.
First you should check if the value of the left table (A) datetime is under 2.5 minutes then approximate to the near 5 min. If it is greater the approximate to the next 5 minutes. The same thing you should do on the right table (B). Or you can do this on the CTE and the right join remains the same as your query.